# File system and file permission

Tags: linux, filesystems

Where does permission of a file reside. Is it attached to the file itself.

I'm uploading a File to a different server. But there was some issue with the uploaded file. The guy who supported us for server says that he doesn't have permission to access the file and check for issues in our code. He asked us to change the file permission and upload again with 755 permission. I'm just wondering that file permission is controlled by FileSystem. And is independent of the permission with which I'm trying to upload. Does it make any sense with the permission that am trying to upload. I believe the permission on my system doesn't persist post uploading.

Answer (score 1):

How do you upload the file? FTP? WWW?

Permissions are stored inside the file system, not within the file itself. However, depending on the transfer method they might also be changed on the server.

Comment: via a Desktop Application. The application doesn't change file permission. Assume it to be something that just transfers via HTTP

Comment: If you use a specialized App for that, you can't be sure what it is doing on the server. It might change the permissions on the server to be exactly the same as they are locally.